# How well does modern VCS deal with thousands of individual repositories or projects?

Tags: version-control, repository, directory-structure

We have a sort of unique situation where we have thousands (20k+) of individual small html files that are unrelated.  We make edits to probably anywhere from 10s to 100s every day.  We have been using Visual Sourcesafe which works well with that model but have been wanting to move to something a bit more modern for a while now.  I just don't know, looking at what is available, what might work best, or if anything will.

Using something like Mercurial, would we want one repo, with one project for each file and all projects in the one repo? Or one repo with one project and all files in that one project? Or will this even work? Or do I know so little about all of this that my question doesn't even make sense (quite possible)?

Answer (score 0):

> do I know so little about all of this that my question doesn't even make sense

Yes, sorry...

- "Project" is unknown entity for VCS (this is an object of another subject area), VCS deals with "repositories"|"files in repositories"
- All (maybe *most*) modern VCS haven't strict limits on amount of files in repositories|amount of repositories, which single server (when it needed /nor always/)can support - except common sense: 20K repositories can be hard job for manage, 20K files in single repo *may* lead to speed's degradation in some edge-cases

Thus: you can|have to choice any model of storing your objects in repository (repositories), just

**Rate and weigh all advantages, disadvantages and consequences of the using of each model** (considering the extreme and intermediate options)

Offhand:

- Repo per file means a lot of repositories on serer and working directories locally but zero of "collateral damage" in any workflow and errors
- One giant repo means all limitation  of "global context" for many action (global revision per repo, inability to branch|tag single file /except SVN/)
- Hashed (by any rule) tree of dirs with files in each container inside will require to have+maintain "location map" and bring additional troubles in case of file-renames (just imagine: `A/a.html A/a1.html` before, `B/b.html C/c.html` after - moved and properly registered in VCS-of-choice - not a big headache, but "rakes in the forehead" is quite possible future)